# Waiting for Admob interstitial ad to load

Tags: android, admob

I want to show an Admob ad whenever the user tries for the first time to exit the app, problem is that when the user does that Admob ad might not be completely loaded, so when it loads it could display when the user is already using some other thing, which doesn't offer a good user experience and it's maybe even against the conditions google sets for using Admob ads.

I've tried to do the previous with the following code, hoping that in the free times the app may have between checking that it's loading and letting the app to sleep for a little time it would keep on loading the add.

```
            while (interstitialAds.isLoading())
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

But it just keeps on using the whole CPU for the while loop.

Any idea on how to be able to code that if the ad is still loading it must wait until it's loaded?

Comment: Calling a sleep on a while like you are doing is giving you a free ticket to the worst place of the hell

Comment: don't load your interstitial Ad on user event, only show preloaded ad

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan, ad starts loading from the beginning, problem is that it might not be completely loaded when the user wants to exit the app, so I'm trying that when the user tries to exit if ad isn't still loaded the app waits for the app to be completely loaded and shows it.

Comment: According to my experience, Ads take few sec to load, if you load in inside `onCreate(..)` method then that is enough. If some how Ad not loaded may be due to very week/poor network  connection, don't show Ad to that user. User experience should be first concern for developer.

Answer (score 3):

Interstitial ads must not be shown on app exit according to Admob policies, avoid it.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Load your ad in the onCreate method as documented in the docs:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
// ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;;;
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

You could also use an [AdListener](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en):

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, problem is that interstitial ad might not be completely loaded when the user wants to exit the app, so I'm trying to not let the app exit if the ad isn't still loaded.

Comment: @user2638180 I guess what you want would violate the ToS of Play Store. Normally an ad loads max 10 sec, at least in my last tests. The ad would be loaded when the user stays in your app that time.